# Page is redirecting to wrong location

Tags: php, session

I'm not sure what I did with my code, but for some reason my link to updatestore.php takes me to admin/index.php. Both of the files below reside in localhost/portal/admin, but I can't fathom what is causing the poor behavior. My session_start() variable resides in ../login.php. I tested taking out session_start from that file and all of my other links started behaving in the same way - they would just take me to admin/index.php instead of where they were supposed to go. I'm at a frustrating loss with what to do.

This is updatestore.php

```
<?php
    require ("../login.php");

    if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 1)
        header('Location: ../index.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['store'] = $_POST['store'];
        header('Location:updatestore2.php');
    }

    include ("header.php");
    include ("adminnav.php");

?>

    <h2>Update Store</h2>

    <?php
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT short_name FROM store ORDER BY short_name");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $num_rows = count($rows);
        if ($num_rows == 0)
            echo '<p>There are no store\'s currently in the system.';
        else { ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <b>Select Store To Edit:</b><br>
                        <select name="store">
                        <?php
                        foreach($rows as $row) {
                            echo '<option value ="'. $row['short_name'] . '">' . $row['short_name'] . '</option>';  
                        }   ?>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <br><input type="submit" value="Select Store" name ="submit" id="submit">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
<?php    } ?>


<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

This is another page that works correctly, addshortages.php

```
<?php
    require ("../login.php");

    if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 1)
        header('Location: ../index.php');

    $success = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['store'] = $_POST['store'];
        header('Location: addshortages2.php');
    }

    include ("header.php");
    include ("adminnav.php");

?>

    <h2>Update Shortages List</h2>

    <?php
        if (!empty($errors))
            foreach($errors as $error)
                echo $error;

        if ($success == true)
            echo '<p>The FAQ has succesfully been submitted!</p>';
    ?>

    <?php

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM store ORDER by short_name");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $num_rows = count($rows);

    ?>
    <?php if ($success == false) { ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <b>Select Store To Modify Shortages:</b><br>
                        <select name="store">
                        <?php
                        foreach($rows as $row) {
                            echo '<option value ="'. $row['short_name'] . '">' . ($row['short_name']) . '</option>';  
                        }   ?>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <br><input type="submit" value="Select Store" name ="submit" id="submit">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
<?php       } ?>

<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

I also have the issue where I try to log-out of my pages, but they just take me to admin/index.php as well. The log-out appends ?logout=1 to a GET variable, but it isn't doing what it is supposed to.

index.php

```
<?php
    require ("login.php");
    require_once ('Bcrypt.php');

    if ((isset($_GET['logout'])) == 1) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1)
            header('Location: admin/index.php');
        else
            header('Location: customer/index.php');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ((empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['password']))) 
            $errors[] = 'Please fill out all fields of the registration process.<br>';
        else {
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
            $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $num_rows = count($rows);
            if ($num_rows) {
                foreach($rows as $row) {
                    $result = Bcrypt::checkPassword($password,$row['password']);
                    if ($result) {
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['id'];
                        $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['admin'];
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                        if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1)
                            header('Location: admin/index.php');
                        else
                            header('Location: customer/index.php');
                    }
                    else
                        $errors[] = 'Your password is incorrect. Please try again.';
                }
            }
            else
                $errors[] = 'We do not have a record of your credentials in our system. To register go <a href="register.php">here</a>. ';
        }

    }

    include ("header.php");
    include ("subnav.php");
?>

    <h2>System Log-In</h2>

    <?php
        if (!empty($errors))
            foreach($errors as $error)
                echo $error;
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <b>E-Mail:*</b> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email"></li>
            <li>
                <b>Password:*</b> <br>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </li>
            <li>
                <br><input type="submit" value="Log-In" name ="submit" id="submit">
            </li>
            <li>
                <br><a href="register.php">Activate Account Here.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                If you are having problems with the log-in process, please send us an <a href="mailto:jayl@jays.us">e-mail</a>.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>


<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

I have tested this situation on IE, Firefox, and Chrome. The updatestore.php file only does NOT work on Firefox. I have no idea why this might be. Also, for IE and Chrome, I have to click the log-out link TWICE before the page logs out and goes to the appropriate location. I'm pulling my hair out here.

Comment: make sure to `exit;` after the `header(...)`.

Comment: Do you have both an `updatestore.php` and `updatestore2.php`?

Comment: Yes I have both of those files. But updatestore2.php doesn't get called until the user submits their information on updatestore.php.

Comment: Have you read my `header('Location:http://google.com');` answer to test if the redirect is ever called?

Comment: I updated my original post. The last paragraph documents the problems that I'm having. The redirects are working, except for the log-out script.

Comment: To get it compatible, you need to `exit;` after your `header(...)` like previously mentioned.
http://pastie.org/7652836

Answer (score 0):

Correct format is to use absolute URLs such as:

```
 header('Location: http://www.site.com/index.php'); 
 header('Location: http://www.site.com/admin/updatestore2.php');
```

but it will work if you dont put a `/` in your url, browser will redirect to current folder's file.

For locating to index from inside admin,

```
 header('Location: /index.php');
```

For locating to admin/updatestore2.php from inside admin:

```
 header('Location: updatestore2.php');
```

These should work

Comment: These aren't the issues. They are supposed to redirect to ../index.php which resides in 'www.site.com/portal/index.php' as opposed to 'www.site.com/portal/admin/index.php' I appreciate the correct format for the URLs, but I am just using my localmachne for a test environment before I deploy to an actual server. Everything with my code was working before. I modified the login.php file to have 'session_start()' included in it, and I did something to mess things up and I don't know what.

Comment: try adding    `session_cache_limiter ('private, must-revalidate');`    just before `session_start()`

Comment: That didn't work, I also was using session_cache_limiter('private, no-expire') earlier and when I ran into problems I removed it and rebooted apache but still encountered the problems.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code is in both pages, but it looks like it's just redirecting you to index.php.

```
if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 1)
        header('Location: ../index.php');
```

But, I have no idea if that's the issue or not.

The functional page has this following it:

```
$success = false;
```

---

This could be causing issue #2:

```
if ((isset($_GET['logout'])) == 1) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: ../index.php');
```

Comment: Only the updatestore.php file isn't working. The other one is. I just don't know what is wrong with the updatestore.php code that is forcing its behavior to be different.

Comment: Exactly. And the $success line doesn't have any impact. I know it's not just a quirk with my server because I've also tested on another host and the same problems.

Comment: Why would that code cause an issue with #2? It worked before.

Comment: Have you tried testing it on another machine? Maybe the server is recognizing you as the admin because of a cookie or something, and other visitors are going to ../index.php as they're supposed to instead of admin/index.php. =X

Comment: Perhaps you have guests set to an admin level, or maybe this line if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 1) means: if user admin level doesn't = 1, then{. Sorry, hope you find the solution.

Comment: If `addshortages2.php` is working while `updatestore.php` or `updatestore2.php` isn't working, then I presume the problem exists in `updatestore.php` or `updatestore2.php`. Try my suggestion with changing the redirect to google once to see if it redirects successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`header('Location:updatestore2.php');`
To:
`header('Location:http://google.com');`
And see if it redirects correctly.
If it does, then your problem resides in `updatestore2.php`.